# Connect to Virtuoso with DotNetRDF

Tags: c#, virtuoso, dotnetrdf

I try to connect to my [Virtuoso Server](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/) with [`dotnetrdf`](https://bitbucket.org/dotnetrdf/dotnetrdf). There is [an example in the documentation](https://bitbucket.org/dotnetrdf/dotnetrdf/wiki/UserGuide/Working%20with%20Graphs) that goes like ...

```
//Create our Storage Provider - this example uses Virtuoso Universal Server
VirtuosoManager virtuoso = new VirtuosoManager("https://myhost.org", 1111, "DB", "username", "password");

//Load the Graph into an ordinary graph instance first
Graph g = new Graph();
virtuoso.LoadGraph(g, new Uri("http://example.org/"));
```

I replaced username and password with my credentials, but when it comes to the `virtuoso.LoadGraph` line, I get a `FormatException` that says:

```
The input string has the wrong format with the following stacktrace:

bei System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)
bei System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info)
bei OpenLink.Data.Virtuoso.TcpConnection.GetEndPoint(String ds)
bei OpenLink.Data.Virtuoso.TcpConnection.Open(ConnectionOptions options)
bei OpenLink.Data.Virtuoso.VirtuosoConnection.CreateInnerConnection(ConnectionOptions options, Boolean enlist)
bei OpenLink.Data.Virtuoso.ConnectionPool.GetConnection(ConnectionOptions options, VirtuosoConnection connection)
bei OpenLink.Data.Virtuoso.VirtuosoConnection.Open()
bei VDS.RDF.Storage.VirtuosoManager.Open(Boolean keepOpen, IsolationLevel level)
bei VDS.RDF.Storage.VirtuosoManager.LoadGraph(IRdfHandler handler, Uri graphUri)
bei VDS.RDF.Storage.VirtuosoManager.LoadGraph(IGraph g, Uri graphUri)
bei VirtuosoTest.MainWindow.LoadGraph() in C:\Users\devfs\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Test\VirtuosoTest\VirtuosoTest\MainWindow.xaml.cs:Zeile 40.
bei VirtuosoTest.MainWindow..ctor() in C:\Users\devfs\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Test\VirtuosoTest\VirtuosoTest\MainWindow.xaml.cs:Zeile 30.
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't help much when trying to figure out what might be wrong. Any idea, what I can do to narrow down the problem?

PS: I can access the Virtuoso conductor via `https://myhost.org:8890/conductor` and I also tried the port `8890` as parameter (but I think this is not the needed port) with the same result. If I omit the port, I get the error, that the target computer refuses the connection.

Thanks in advance,
Frank

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue lies here --

```
VirtuosoManager("https://myhost.org", 1111, "DB", "username", "password");
```

The `dotnetrdf` connection is not via `http/https`; the first argument should just be a hostname, i.e., `myhost.org`.

Simply changing the above to the following should resolve the immediate error --

```
VirtuosoManager("myhost.org", 1111, "DB", "username", "password");
```

Comment: That's it! Thank you very much!